# Populate C# dictionary in async via conditional arguments before access from threads reading dictionary contents

Tags: c#, dictionary, asynchronous, async-await

I am working on an `async` application that populates a dictionary with key-value pairs of data from one system and then uses the dictionary to determine if a second system has data that matches. The issue is that the dictionary does not complete populating its data before other threads try to lookup data in the key-value pairs, yielding incorrect results.

I tried converting the original code, which is a void method, to an async method that returns a task. Something that starts like

```
async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> CreateGALEmailTypesDictionary(IEnumerable<InterActionQueryResult_BaseClass>? interActionClientAllRecords, SearchResultCollection ADClientAllRecords)
```

but because all the logic inside the method relies on conditional statements and no additional async, I could not see a way to use `await`, or `Task.WhenAll`.

Below is the original code for populating the dictionary. How could I use this logic in an async application and insure that the dictionary populates before any other processes read the data it contains?

```
public void ReviewGALEmailTypesForDeletions(IEnumerable<InterActionQueryResult_BaseClass>? interActionClientAllRecords, SearchResultCollection ADClientAllRecords)
{
    string? InterAction_GAL_EmailType = string.Empty;
    string? AD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction = string.Empty;

    if (interActionClientAllRecords is not null)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> InterActionGALEmailTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (InterActionQueryResult_BaseClass interActionClientRecord in interActionClientAllRecords)
        {
            //InterAction GAL Email Types can contain spaces, but AD GAL Email Types cannot. Spaces removed for later matching.
            if (interActionClientRecord.InterActionEmailType is null)
                InterAction_GAL_EmailType = string.Empty;
            else
                InterAction_GAL_EmailType = interActionClientRecord.InterActionEmailType.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            if (interActionClientRecord.GALEmailType is null)
                interActionClientRecord.GALEmailType = string.Empty;
            else
                AD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction = interActionClientRecord.GALEmailType.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            if (!InterActionGALEmailTypes.ContainsKey(InterAction_GAL_EmailType))
                InterActionGALEmailTypes.Add(InterAction_GAL_EmailType, AD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction);
        }
//Look up ADClientAllRecords in dictionary
```

### Update

Per @StriplingWarrior's post I am attempting to use `TaskCompletionSource` and `Lazy<T>` to populate a `ConcurrentDictionary` via a `foreach`, after which the populated `ConcurrentDictionary` is evaluated by conditional statements. I am using a `ConcurrentDictionary` so that I can have access to the `ContainsKey`, `GetOrAdd`, and `TryGetValue` methods while using `Lazy<T>`.

Unfortunately, even though the code compiles and runs, I am still unable to populate the `ConcurrentDictionary` without incorrect evaluations via the conditional statements. Here is my code at this point:

**Code That Calls ConcurrentDictionary Creation (with edits 10-4-2023)**

```
public void ReviewGALEmailTypesForDeletions(IEnumerable<InterActionQueryResult_BaseClass>? interActionClientAllRecords, SearchResultCollection ADClientAllRecords)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<string>> InterActionGALEmailTypes = GetDictionaryInstanceAsync(interActionClientAllRecords).Result;

    if (interActionClientAllRecords is not null)
    {
        if (ADClientAllRecords.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (SearchResult ADClientRecord in ADClientAllRecords)
            {
                string ADGALEmailType = (string)ADClientRecord.Properties["extensionAttribute7"][0];
                long ADEmailIdAsLong = Convert.ToInt64(ADClientRecord.Properties["extensionAttribute8"][0]);

                if (!InterActionGALEmailTypes.ContainsKey(ADGALEmailType)) //AD GAL Type not a record in iA
                    ADContactMgmt.MoveADContact(2, ADEmailIdAsLong, ActionTypes.MoveGALEmailTypeMissing);
                else
                {
                    Lazy<string> interActionGALEmailTypeValue;
                    bool valueExists = InterActionGALEmailTypes.TryGetValue(ADGALEmailType, out interActionGALEmailTypeValue);

                    if (interActionGALEmailTypeValue.ToString() != ADGALEmailType) //iA GAL Type value not equal to AD GAL Type
                        ADContactMgmt.MoveADContact(2, ADEmailIdAsLong, ActionTypes.MoveGALEmailTypeMissing);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code that Populates ConcurrentDictionary (with additional code 10-4-2023)**

```
private Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<string>>> GetDictionaryInstanceAsync(IEnumerable<InterActionQueryResult_BaseClass>? interActionClientAllRecords)
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        return instance;
    }

    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<string>>>(LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly, 
        TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    
    instance = completionSource.Task;

    ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<string>> InterActionGALEmailTypes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<string>>();

    //Populate ConcurrentDictionary
    string? InterAction_GAL_EmailType = string.Empty;
    string? AD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction = string.Empty;

    if (interActionClientAllRecords is not null)
    {
        foreach (InterActionQueryResult_BaseClass interActionClientRecord in interActionClientAllRecords)
        {
            //InterAction GAL Email Types can contain spaces, but AD GAL Email Types cannot. Spaces removed for later matching.
            if (interActionClientRecord.InterActionEmailType is null)
                InterAction_GAL_EmailType = string.Empty;
            else
                InterAction_GAL_EmailType = interActionClientRecord.InterActionEmailType.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            if (interActionClientRecord.GALEmailType is null)
                interActionClientRecord.GALEmailType = string.Empty;
            else
                AD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction = interActionClientRecord.GALEmailType.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            if (!InterActionGALEmailTypes.ContainsKey(InterAction_GAL_EmailType))
            {
                Lazy<string> lazyAD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction = new Lazy<string>(() => new string(AD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction));
                InterActionGALEmailTypes.GetOrAdd(InterAction_GAL_EmailType, lazyAD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction);
            }
        }

        completionSource.SetResult(InterActionGALEmailTypes);
        return completionSource.Task;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `async` in order to produce a `Task`. Consider this example:

```
Task<Dictionary<string, string>> instance;

Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetInstanceAsync()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        return instance;
    }
    
    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Dictionary<string, string>>(TaskCreationsOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    instance = completionSource.Task;
    
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    // Populate Dictionary //
    
    completionSource.SetResult(dictionary);
    return completionSource;
}
```

Once the `instance` is set, future calls to this function will return the Task from the TaskCompletionSource. Any continuations on that task will only execute after this function calls `SetResult`.

Note that for simplicity this does not lock the thread, so there's a slight possibility that multiple threads could end up doing the work of initializing the dictionary. This is only safe to do if initializing the dictionary is an *idempotent* operation. It is roughly analogous to using a [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-lazy-1-ctor(system-func((-0)))) with [`LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode?view=net-7.0#system-threading-lazythreadsafetymode-publicationonly).

In fact, I'd recommend you consider using `Lazy<T>` instead: the only advantage this code gives you is that other tasks can asynchronously `await` the Task, freeing up the threads for other uses while they wait for the Dictionary to be created. Unless it's taking a *long time* to create your dictionary, you're probably better off allowing those threads to block and avoiding the extra complexity and overhead of using `Task`s.

If the creation of the Dictionary ever *does* involve some kind of asynchronous processing, you could use a `Lazy<Task<Dictionary, string>>` instead.

Comment: It is generally advisable to initialize the `TaskCompletionSource` with the [`TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) option, otherwise the thread that completes it (with `SetResult`) might be hijacked by the continuations of the task.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Thank you. I learned something new today. :-)

Comment: Thank you @StriplingWarrior. I very much appreciate all the useful information you've provided. I have been working with `Lazy<T>` and `TaskCompletionSource` but without successfully populating  a `Dictionary` or a `ConcurrentDictionary` before its data is being accessed by threads. I posted an update in my question should you wish to see the code I've written. Any additional assistance would be very welcome.

Comment: @joeschwa: I think it's likely you're misdiagnosing the issue a little because your code is overcomplicated.  The code you posted sets `AD_GAL_EmailTypeInInterAction` to `string.Empty`, never sets it to anything else, and then uses it in a closure. If that value is getting set by the "additional conditional statements", then the variable in your closure is going to be different by the time the loop completes. You can try moving the declaration for `InterAction_GAL_EmailType` inside the `for` loop. But there are other warning signs here so that might not be enough to fix all your problems.

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior. Omitting the additional conditional statements made the code harder to understand, so for posterity I've added them. And yes, I agree it's overcomplicated. I ended up revisiting the requirements and rewrote the methods without using a dictionary, so my issue is resolved. In hindsight, I don't think it's possible to use a `Dictionary` or `ConcurrentDictionary` in `async` the way I intended. I very much appreciate all your help. I learned a lot!

Comment: The problem isn't with async/Dictionary/ConcurrentDictionary. The code you posted has a lot of code smells. Why is `interActionClientAllRecords` an argument? If it's variable, how can a single instance be correct? Can it really have duplicate keys and, if so, why is taking the first value from among those keys the best strategy? Can it really be null? If so, you'd want to return a Task with a null result, not a null Task. ConcurrentDictionary, Lazy, and `new string()` aren't helping you. I'm glad you learned, though, and I'm glad you found a fix.